# Using Google Apps Script to add A UiApplication for Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-apps

I want to show a prompt or a ui application if i receive or send a message. Is it possible to do this? If yes, how? is it like adding uiapplication on google docs?

Comment: Could you be more accurate in your description please?  How do you imagine the workflow and in which context?

Comment: I need the user to input some text about the message. For example, I received a message from sender1. A uiapplication should appear(my intention) allowing me to input a certain text and storing it in a variable that will be used in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no trigger that fires on email reception or sending, the only thing you can do is poll the new threads and see if something new has been received.

There is no way to make an app "appear" without user action, triggers are unable to launch webapp Ui's.

You could imagine to build an app that shows a list of the most recent messages and manage to write some form of comments about it before storing it in a log sheet but this begins to be quite far from what you imagine isn't it ?

Why not simply forward each email you want to comment to yourself with a specific title and build a filter that automatically add a label to it ? Gmail (and other email client softwares) has also a desktop notification that works in real time and pops up whenever a new message is coming.

Then a backend script (running on a timer) could grab all messages in that label and process them the way you want.